# Knockout validationis not updating error message according to the validation specification

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, knockout-validation

I am trying to show different validation messages based on a provided condition, but the messages are not displayed properly. All methods used in this function are working fine as per requirement.

I am attaching the code:

```
self.pickupCloseTime.extend({
    required: {
        message: "Please select Close time.",
    },
    validation: {
        validator: function (val) {
            if (val == "") {
                this.message = "Please select Close time.";
                return false;
            }
            else if (self.pickupReadyTime() != "") {
                var readyTime = moment(self.pickupReadyTime(), "hh:mm A");
                var closeTime = moment(val, "hh:mm A");

                if (closeTime.diff(readyTime) > 0 
                      && (closeTime.diff(readyTime) / 3600) < 2000) {
                    this.message = 'Please select valid Close time.';
                    return false;
                }
                else if (closeTime.diff(readyTime) <= 0) {
                  this.message = "Close time should be greater than Ready time.";
                  return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            else {
                this.message = 'Please select Ready Time first.'
                return false;
            }
        },
        message: "Close time should be greater than Ready time.",
        params: true
    }
});
```

Please help.

Comment: can you create a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practise is to split them into smaller validation cases, each with its own condition and message.

You can also add them as custom validation rules to be **reused**, and here is an example:

```
define(['knockout',
    'data/settings',
    'services/resourceService'],
function (ko, settings, resourceService) {

    ko.validation.rules['closeTimeNotValid'] = {
        // check if close time is Valid
        validator: function (val) {
            //example rule
            return val != "" && val > 0;
        },
        message: "Please select valid Close time."
    };
            return ko.validation.rules;
});
```

Then you can use/reuse this rule if needed:

```
self.pickupCloseTime.extend({
    required: {
        message: "Please select Close time."
    },
    closeTimeNotValid: {
        message: "Message overrides the custom rule's message",
        //add more rules/conditions to the main one, you can also 
        //set params here to be used in the custom validation
        onlyIf: function () { return self.someOtherField(); }
    }
});
```